# ¿Es posible poner 2 onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

actualmente tengo esto

```
<li><a class="tablinks_ tab__active__" onclick="openCategory(event, '__IMAGEN1__1')">IMAGEN1</a></li>
<li><a class="tablinks_ tab__active__" onclick="openCategory(event, '__IMAGEN__2')">IMAGEN1</a></li>
<li><a class="tablinks_ tab__active__" onclick="openCategory(event, '__IMAGEN__3')">IMAGEN2</a></li>
<li><a class="tablinks_ tab__active__" onclick="openCategory(event, '__IMAGEN__4')">IMAGEN3</a></li>
```

Y lo que quiero hacer es como añadir otro `onclick` a las etiquetas `<a>`

Comment: Supongo que quieres ejecutar 2 funciones a la vez, si te refieres a eso, lo fácil es hacer una tercera función que llame a las otras dos y pones ésta, la tercera, en el onclick... a ésta tercera función le pasas los parámetros que necesites en las otras dos. Es una opción sencilla aunque muy mejorable.

Comment: no veo el por que uses la etiqueta java, si el código que muestras es JavaScript

Comment: [Esta pregunta sobre asociación de eventos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/61910/250) te puede ser de utilidad. Como recomendación, es mejor no tener `onclick` (separar la vista del controlador siempre es una buena idea, hasta el punto de que algunos sistemas no te permiten tenerlo así).

Answer (score 2):

Para `JavaScript` puedes hacer esto:

```
onclick="hacerAlgo();hacerAlgoMas();"
```

Pero realmente, es mejor que no uses `onclick` que conectes el controlador de eventos al nodo DOM a través de tu código `JavaScript`. Esto se conoce como [javascript discreto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Además como te plantea @track3r en su comentario, puedes hacer algo como esto:

**Un enlace con 1 función definida**

```
<a href="#" onclick="tuFuncionDefinida()">Haz clic en mí para activar algunas funciones</a>
```

**Disparando múltiples funciones desde tuFuncionDefinida()**

```
function tuFuncionDefinida() {
    mostrarAlert();
    validar();
    otraFuncion();
    otraFunctionMas();
}
```

Mira si te sirve, Saludos!

Answer (score -1):

Mira a ver si te sirve. Al hacer click en la "IMAGEN1", se ejecutan los dos eventos click: por id y por class.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#click").click(function(event) {
        alert("click0");
      });
      $(".click1").click(function(event) {
        alert("click1");
      });
    });
  </script>
  <li><a class="tablinks_ tab__active__ click1" id="click">IMAGEN1</a></li>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: explica mas tu respuesta